# Finite Series Identity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

EDIT: I stated a FALSE question, because I understood bad. Please read again.

How to prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+k)} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{n = 1}^{k} \frac{1}{n}$$

using only basic methods? 
I tried to split the series, obtaining (omitting the Series index)

$$\sum \frac{1}{kn} - \sum \frac{1}{k(n+k)}$$

and the first term is ok. But this would imply the second term is zero.
Sums are always meant to be for $n = 1$ to $\infty$.

Any hint?

Comment: This works for integer $k$.  You might consider adding that condition to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement isn't true.

You can show inductively on $M$, using your approach, that $$\sum_{n=1}^M \frac{1}{n(n+k)} = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=M+1}^{M+k}\frac{1}{n}$$

Use this to prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+k)} =\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: I don't get the first passage. Why the superior extrema of the sum becomes $k$? How can it?

Comment: No idea what you mean. Be more specific. @Henry I did tell you quite clearly how to prove it. You'll see why it is true if you try to prove the induction.

Comment: Oh sorry! I meant: you started with a sum from 1 to $M$ which is equal to two sums, the first of them goes from 1 to $k$. Why? I mean , why to $k$? >.< Sorry if it's a stupid question!

Comment: Just try it out. You cancel, and you are left with $2k$ terms, because of your reduction of $\frac{1}{n(n+k)}=\frac{1}k\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+k}\right)$. Again, just try the induction, and you will see how the cancelling occurs.

Comment: ............. Done!!

Comment: Altnerative, see what happens when $k=1$.

Comment: Isn't the telescope a wonderful tool?  ;-))  +1 for the clear and concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{n(n+k)} = \frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+k}\right)$, whence $\sum\limits_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n(n+k)} = \frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{n=1}^k\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+k}\right)$. But now the proposition does not seem to be true.

Comment: What if $k\to\infty$?

Comment: Do you want $k\to \infty$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+k)}$? As $k\to\infty$ you have something completely different. Specifically, your statement is, again, not true if $k\to\infty$, but is true if we take $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$.

Comment: Edited! I wrote wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If $k=1$ your proposition becomes
$$\frac{1}{2} = 1$$

so it's false. Even for greater $k$ it still remains false.